# Paypal Live credentials and Sandbox credentials in same site

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi can I use Paypal Live credentials and Sandbox credentials in same site , 
Sandbox will be used by sellers to test their payment flow and live will be used by buyers

Answer (score 0):

No. when you turn off your sandbox mode in paypal, you will not be able to use https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr